# What is the best transformer to generate text based on a dataset?

Tags: transformers

I'm working with huggingface to run TensorFlow models locally. I'm using this as a learning exercise since I've never worked with AI before (I'm more interested in learning the process than the actual result). I want to use AI to process a dataset and identify the emails in the dataset that are credit card charges and extract the card terminal, bank, amount, description and whether it was approved or denied. I'm still not sure how I would train the model, but the first question would be:

**What is the best transformer to generate a line of text based on each credit-card-charge email in the dataset?**
E.j.

> 1234 YourBank ChargeDescription Approved

Comment: I see the question is being downvoted without an explanation of why it's a bad question... It's one question, focused, with an example... I fail to see why it's not good.

Answer (score 1):

The famous models for answering questions on a dataset are Tabert (old and not maintained), then Tapas.  Neither works in Windows.

Comment: Thanks! That last comment is important, because I am running it on Windows.